# How to subclass with base class data retain in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

How i can pass data from First screen to Second screen provided that must use inheritance and data entered in base class should be available in second screen after push.

```
class FirstViewController {
  var dataArray = [CustomModel]()
 //methods will manupulate data
}
```

Then push subclass SecondViewController from class FirstViewController

```
class SecondViewController : FirstViewController  {
   print(dataArray)
}
```

Is this possible ? any solution to this ? I just wanted reuse most of code in many screens. Any help.

Comment: How are you pushing SecondViewController from FirstViewController?

Comment: @PGDev. self.navigationController.pushViewController(). When i push not getting FirstViewController Value. getting nil.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit class B with parent class A, then you can access its data members.
Here check this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //call show function of class B which is inherit from class A
        let classB = B()
        classB.showData()
        
    }
}

class A {
    var dataArray:  [String] = ["ABC", "123", "XYZ"]
}

class B: A {
    func showData()
    {
        print(dataArray)
    }
}
```

Output:
`["ABC", "123", "XYZ"]`

This is basic rule of inheritance, is this what you are looking for! if not kindly explain your problem in detail.

P.S
you can also use static data members they are accessible without making object.